# Is it possible to send a direct message to a user?

Tags: javascript, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm fairly new to programming within the YouTube Data API and I have an inquiry on whether it is possible to perform the task that I wish to in JavaScript.

When someone subscribes to my channel, I want it to send them an automated direct message saying that I appreciate your subscription, alternative platforms on where I may be located when I'm unavailable on YouTube and resources on how to correctly configure your notification settings to inform you of every new video that is published.

Also, when someone posts an inappropriate comment on a video, it will automatically delete the comment and I want it to send them an automated direct message informing them that their comment was deleted and the Engagement Guidelines for the channel state that the offending content is in violation of them.

Would this be possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is really no way of knowing when someone subscribes to your channel.   You do get a new email when someone has subscribed but there is no way to contact them as you are not given any information beyond their youtube account which wont help you contact them.

even [subscriptions.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list) does not return any information about who actually subscribed.

No what you want to do is not possible.  However its an intesting idea it may be worth adding a feature request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803)